# How to define a global javascript method in webpack packs for rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I found many questions about making a variable or function global in Javascript (& generally I understand it is not a good practice), but sometimes we need to avail JS functions across the application, doing this in Webpacker for our Rails 5 application usually is done like this:

In a `useful_pack.js` file

```
function globalFunction() {
   // some stuff
}
export {globalFunction }
```

Then in `application.js`, we import the pack & bind the global function to window:

```
import { globalFunction } from  useful_pack.js
// some code
window.globalFunction = globalFunction
```

Is there any major drawback for binding to window in this case? is there a more standard way to avail a global JS function in webpacker ? (so that I can call the function in any view in my rails app)

Comment: I do not share the opinion that global functions are bad at all. The can be harmful if they get reassigned or overwritten but if global functions would be bad at all, window.encodeURIComponent would be bad also.

For me it looks like you are not coding in javascript, you use javascript to build an angular or react app or something like this, but then the framework restricts you to local functions. They do not want you to use regular vanillaJS in your app.

Comment: Global standard function do not count as bad practice but making new global functions have some drawbacks (but of course you might have a different opinion), here I am using React & vanilla JS in this app & I have used JS in many frameworks, the question here is specifically for the best practice to do this in Rails & webpacker

Answer (score 0):

To add a function in the global scope, to make it available across your application, this is the recommended way:

```js
global.globalFunction = function() {
  // some stuff
};

// or

const globalFunction = () => {
  // some stuff
};
global.globalFunction = globalFunction;
```